# Dynamically provide fields in getRecord wire adapter based on object

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to make the getRecord dynamic so as to be able to provide fields based on a condition?

I tried below code but the wire is not getting invoked:

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";

import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

const ACCOUNT_FIELDS = ["Account.Name"];
const CONTACT_FIELDS = ["Contact.LastName"];

export default class GetRecordBasedOnContext extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: this.fields() })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            // get values from fields based on object API name
            console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data));
        } else if (error) {
            console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }

    fields() {
        if (this.objectApiName === "Account") {
            return ACCOUNT_FIELDS;
        } else {
            return CONTACT_FIELDS;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why code in question didn't work, but the fix is to:

1. Change the `fields` function to a getter property.
2. Pass the fields getRecord as reactive, this is mentioned in document ([Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_wire_service_about)):

   > `In the wire adapter’s configuration object, prefix a value with $ to reference a property of the component instance. The $ prefix tells the wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as this.propertyName.

Code:

```js
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: "$fields" })
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        // get values from fields based on object API name
        console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    } else if (error) {
        console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}

get fields() {
    if (this.objectApiName === "Account") {
        return ACCOUNT_FIELDS;
    } else if() {
        return CONTACT_FIELDS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very slick @Raul wasn't aware of this feature